# 22.04 cannot Automatically Suspend my Lenovo laptop

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, suspend, power-management, lenovo

I have Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS with 42.9 GNOME. Settings for "automatic suspend" in Power tab are "On"+"10 minutes" for both On Battery Power and Plugged In.

When laptop is kept untouched, a notification "**Automatic hibernation Suspending soon because of inactivity**" is shown after approximately 5 minutes, but suspend does not happen.

Manual suspend, which is a problem for a lot of people out there, is working fine for me, both using `systemctl suspend -i` and just menu option, and some parts of Automatic Suspend routine are also functioning, as I'm getting the notification, but something prevents an actual suspend.

`dmesg | less` shows only messages from **[UFW BLOCK]** and **audit** during the idle period, none of them are errors.

I am experiencing this both with nvidia-driver-470 (proprietary) and nvidia-driver-535 (proprietary, tested), both using discrete and dynamic graphics.

Wifi chip is

```
$ lspci -nn | grep 0280

00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:43f0] (rev 11)
```

Switching radio module to Airplane mode does not help

Comment: It's it a laptop? Sometimes WiFi activity may prevent suspend. Edit your question and add information about your WiFi chip, it your commuter has one and if it is turned on.